# Vaadin float field (from the String field Validation)

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin8

I tried to create a float field in Vaadin from String field (I dont know any other method ;)

I have a validation which should allow me that a String field will be just a float field. I found only a solution for an integer? How to asure that my user can type only float  number?

```
@Override
public void setConfiguration(EditorConfiguration editorConfiguration) {
    Validator<String> validator = ((FloatFieldConfiguration) editorConfiguration).getValidator();
    if (validator != null) {
        binder.forField(this).withValidator(validator)
                .withConverter(new StringToFloatConverter("Must enter a number"))
                .bind(s -> getValue(), (b, v) -> setValue(v));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There can be various ways to achieve your purpose but I would recommend you to use the custom converter by implementing the `Converter` Interface.

Here is something that you can try:

```
class CustomConverter implements Converter<String, Double> {
  @Override
  public Result<Double> convertToModel(String fieldValue, ValueContext context) {
// Produces a converted value or an error
try {
  // ok is a static helper method that creates a Result
  return Result.ok(Double.valueOf(fieldValue));
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  // error is a static helper method that creates a Result
  return Result.error("Please enter a decimal value");
  }
}
  //for business object
 @Override
  public String convertToPresentation(Double dbl, ValueContext context) 
    {
// Converting to the field type should always succeed,
// so there is no support for returning an error Result.
return String.valueOf(dbl);
 }
}
```

After that you can simply call  `CustomConverter` inside the `withConverter()` method.(like `.withConverter(new CustomConverter()).bind()`). This is the ideal way to define your conversions(if you want something exactly as you wish.)

Hope it serves your purpose..:)